# Angular ngx-datatable CSS

Tags: css, angular, ngx-datatable

How to style a row in ngx-datatable component? Here is an example in component's documentation:
https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#css

When I run same demo only one row has background color set.
[Here is my demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cvzaov?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to style properly the child component from the parent component, you can use one of the methods specified in [this link](https://www.mmbyte.com/article/11483.html). Preferably use the answer 3 in the link which will prevent the use of deprecated selector like :deep:. You can fix the color not appearing in even rows by

```
/deep/ .age-is-ten {  background: #ffc91f !important;}
```

Comment: Tried and the result is same. Only one row changed background.

Comment: .ngx-datatable.bootstrap .datatsable-body .datatable-body-row.datatable-row-even -> this css seems to be over writing you background color